# Get the oauth_token and oauth_verifier from the link

Tags: passport.js, twitter-oauth

I am using passport.js for twitter oauth authentication.
At the redirection stage I get the link which looks like this:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/twitter/callback?oauth_token=vneuOwAAAAABGGAAAAABc4EdbOs&oauth_verifier=j5zYOuk4WsYU1vB24DUEc59qmBWAWbso

as you can see the oauth_token and oauth_verifier are in the link, what is the correct way to get these information?
Note: this is the part where I call the authentication

```
app.get('/login/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'));
app.get('/login/twitter/callback',
passport.authenticate('twitter', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect:'/' })  
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my problem was the successRedirect, now I redirect if succeeded after authentication and it works.

```
app.get('/login/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'));

app.get('/login/twitter/callback',
passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect:'/' }),
function(req,res){
  const access_token = req.query.oauth_token;
  const access_token_secret = req.query.oauth_verifier;
  res.redirect('/');
}  
  );
```